# Guice default binding singleton or factory?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class Xyz which is injected into multiple classes. I use Guice for DI.

```
    class Xyz{
        
        static int i =0;
        
        public Xyz(){
          System.out.println("###########creating instance = " + (++i));
        }
    }
   

    class ManagedOne{
    
         Xyx xyz;
        
        public ManagedOne(Xyz xyz){
         this.xyz = xyz;
        }
    }

    class ManagedTwo{
    
        Xyx xyz;
    
        public ManagedTwo(Xyz xyz){
         this.xyz = xyz;
        }
    }
```

Guice

```
  bind(Xyz.class).in(Singleton.class);
  bind(ManageOne.class).in(Singleton.class);
  bind(ManageTwo.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

1. Now even if i remove the about binding i still see that Guice is creating singleton instance of Xyz. Verified using the sysout. It only prints it one with value 1. Is this the default behavior? I thought default was factory.
2. Will Guice inject same instance of Xyz in both the managers? If yes, Is the code  `bind(Xyz.class).in(Singleton.class)` redundant then?

Note that i donot use `injector.getInstance(Xyz.class)` to get instance of Xyz all the time. Rather i do it the way i showed in my code above

Comment: You didn't provide the full and correct definition of `Xyz`: the first line you wrote is `class Xyz() {` with `()` that shouldn't be here. So I guess you adapted your code shown. Also after I removed the `()`, I ran your code with `var injector = Guice.createInjector(); injector.getInstance(Xyz.class); injector.getInstance(Xyz.class); injector.getInstance(Xyz.class);` and got the expected result `###########creating instance = 1
###########creating instance = 2
###########creating instance = 3` Therefore please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is a sample code and not actual code that i run in my system since actual code is quite complex. I edit the post. Also note that i donot create instance of Xyz using injector. See my  updated post.

Comment: The default binding is for factories; what you've posted should work. Note that ManageOne and ManageTwo will actually need to be created themselves in order for Guice to create Xyz, so if you don't make it a point to create instances of both ManagedOne and ManagedTwo, you won't see the counter increase.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any issue.

Given that `count` is `static`, make sure that your entire app is not called twice, that you don't have several injectors or similar. Or even that you don't call `new Xyz()` by hand.

I made two tests in one. `Abc` is not annotated with `@Singleton`, while `Xyz` is annotated with `@Singleton`.

```
import com.google.inject.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    var injector = Guice.createInjector();
    var module1 = injector.getInstance(Module1.class);
    var module2 = injector.getInstance(Module2.class);
    if (module1.abc == module2.abc) {
      System.out.println("Only one instance of Abc");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Two instances of Abc");
    }
    if (module1.xyz == module2.xyz) {
      System.out.println("Only one instance of Xyz");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Two instances of Xyz");
    }
  }

  static class Abc {
    static int count = 0;
    Abc() { System.out.println("Abc #" + ++count); }
  }

  @Singleton static class Xyz {
    static int count = 0;
    Xyz() { System.out.println("Xyz #" + ++count); }
  }

  @Singleton static class Module1 {
    final Abc abc;
    final Xyz xyz;
    @Inject Module1(Abc abc, Xyz xyz) { this.abc = abc; this.xyz = xyz; }
  }

  @Singleton static class Module2 {
    final Abc abc;
    final Xyz xyz;
    @Inject Module2(Abc abc, Xyz xyz) { this.abc = abc; this.xyz = xyz; }
  }

}
```

The result is the following:

```
Abc #1
Xyz #1
Abc #2
Two instances of Abc
Only one instance of Xyz
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please make a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exactly showcases your issue rather than vaguely explaining.